# DAX measure to sum only numeric values on string column with both numbers and strings

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to create DAX measure to sum up only numeric values? Suppose we have simple sample data as below. 
[image]

I thought that this code might do the job, but it failed.

```
m1 = IF( MAX(Table1[category]) = "apples", SUM(Table1[units]) , BLANK() )
```

When I try to add this measure to the table, which has applied filters for apples and plums only, I get the error message:

[image]

I need something that will apply filter first, seeding out text values, then do the summing up on numeric values only.

Comment: By design, a  database can only store one datatype in a column.  The only way you could include those mix of values is to store them as strings.  While it can be done- making sense of the data afterwards is problematic since the intent is to select certain strings over other strings, converting the applicable strings to integers.  This requires running a function over the entire data- 'unpacking' in a sense, which is a violation of 1NF in database design.

Comment: Nevertheless, for the sake of flexibility, it is convenient to have mixed values and sum only numeric values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a terrible way to store data, but it is possible to do what you're asking.

Try this measure, for example,

```
= SUMX(FILTER(Table1, Table1[type]="number"), VALUE(Table1[units]))
```

The `VALUE` function converts the string to a numeric value and we only sum over the rows where the `type` is "number".

Comment: Marvelous answer! Critical comment and delivered solution is usually better then just critical comment. Thank you:-)

Comment: Maybe it should be asked as another question. How would you write the measure if two filters should be applied on separate tables? Can't figure that out.

Comment: Yes, that should be a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that SUM will never work on a column that is defined as being text.  So for example if your column was only numbers, but the column defined as text then `Measure:= SUM ( table[ units] )` would always error.

The only way to really do what you want would to be having the data in separate columns by type.  Then having within a calculated measure which returns based on the column.

Comment: Definitely having the data in separate columns by type would be ONE of the solutions. I think you are taking about M. I do not know if this is the only solution. Probably there is a way in DAX to return filtered table and then do summation on it. I have lots of columns and I would prefer not to mess around in M if I can do it in DAX.

Answer (score 0):

Try this measure

```
=
SUMX (
    FILTER ( Tablename, Table1[category] = "apples" ),
    IFERROR ( VALUE ( Table1[units] ), 0 )
)
```

Comment: This formula has a syntax error. Please test it before posting.

Comment: It is still not correct syntax. Please use daxformatter.com then you will have validation of the code.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin updated, plz check

Comment: IFERROR is not an elegant approach to me because it will fail in unexpected cases. You would have to handle other data types like Boolean, or date.

Comment: It worked for me; however, if any other data types come into play, it will set values to 0.