# Column has some rows containing numbers and others with text

Tags: powerbi

I have an excel sheet, which I have no permissions to adjust. There's a column which has some rows with a number (existing client licence fee), others with "yes" (possible future client) and other rows with "No".

I am looking to be able to add the numbers for information such as how much money we are getting on certain products, count the "Yes" to see how many potential clients we can target, and count "No" to see how many clients will have no interest in each particular module.

I could split out into separate columns, one with numbers and the other being a yes/no column and then I could count them. However, I'd prefer not to have to create new columns in power bi. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Creating columns is most of the time better (you have here strings and numbers in one column which is not good) but if you dont want to do it, you can use DAX expressions:

```
=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(YourTable), YourTable[YourColumn] = "Yes")
=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(YourTable), YourTable[YourColumn] = "No")
```

And for the sum you could use this answer:

[DAX measure to sum only numeric values on string column with both numbers and strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742315/dax-measure-to-sum-only-numeric-values-on-string-column-with-both-numbers-and-st)